# ERC721 _holderTokens

Tags: solidity, erc-721

The ERC721.sol provided by OpenZeppelin has a variable _holderTokens which is private. If I am writing my smart contract which inherits from ERC721.sol, is there any way to make that variable public so everyone can access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question, we could access the owner of an ERC721 token by using the ownerOf function.